Wordpress : Store a data in the back so and in JS to remove this if deleted
I have an issue to understand how to proceed. I have a image button to generate the list of the page under the button ( the title and date of the page). Theses pages are added in the page menu of Wordpress dashboard. The problem I have is when I delete the page in the wordpress dashbord or the database, the list of the page generated is still displayed. It should not because the post was deleted from the data.
`
<?php

/**
 * Class WoosterPartnerPresentation
 * Sets up functionalities for displaying presentation content in the Wooster plugin.
 */
class WoosterPartnerPresentation
{
    /**
     * Constructor function for initializing the class.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        ob_start();
        // Hooks the presentation content function to the wooster_presentation_content action.
        add_action('wooster_presentation_content', array($this, 'woosterShowPresentation'));
        add_action('wooster_presentation_content', array($this, 'woosterPartnerPluginSection'));
        add_action('wooster_presentation_content', array($this, 'woosterPartnerPluginSectionSetup'));
        add_action('wooster_presentation_content', array($this, 'create_post')); //admin init is triggered when wp admin is initialized
        add_action('wp_ajax_create_post', [$this, 'create_post']);
        add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_create_post', [$this, 'create_post']);
        add_action('wp_ajax_delete_post', [$this, 'ajax_delete_post']);
        add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_delete_post', [$this, 'ajax_delete_post']);

    }
    /**
     * Callback function to display presentation content.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function woosterShowPresentation()
    {
        // FIXME: Concatenate the content in one variable and echo it at the end.
        echo '<div class="wooster-presentation">';
        echo '<p> Générez une page de présentation et personnalisez le </p>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
    public function ispluginElementorActive()
    {
        return is_plugin_active('elementor/elementor.php') ? true : false;
    }
    /*
     * Add a new section for the Form to select the page constructor
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function woosterPartnerPluginSectionSetup()
    {
        // Add a new section to a settings page.
        add_settings_section('partner_badges_section2', __('Choississez votre constructeur de page'), array($this, 'woosterPartnerPluginSection'), 'wooster_form', array());
    }

    /**
     * Callback function to display the form for selecting the page constructor.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function woosterPartnerPluginSection()
    {
?>
     <section class="presentation-content">
        <?php
        do_settings_sections('wooster_gutenberg');
        ?>

        <h2>Générateurs de page</h2>
        <p>Choissisez le constructeur de page que vous préférez : </p> <?php
        do_settings_sections('wooster_form');
        // Conditionally display the buttons based on the presence and activation of Elementor plugin
        if ($this->ispluginElementorActive()) {
            ?>
         <div style="display: flex;">
        <form method="POST" action="">
                    <input type="hidden" name="submit-gutenberg" value="gutenberg">
                    <input type="image" src="<?php echo plugins_url('assets/img/group.png', __FILE__); ?>" alt="Logo HubSpot" width=100% height=100%/>
                </form>
                <form method="POST" action="">
                    <input type="hidden" name="submit-elementor" value="elementor">
                    <input type="image"src="<?php echo plugins_url('assets/img/Elementor.png', __FILE__); ?>" width=100% height=100%/>
                </form>
            </div>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <div style="display: flex;">
                <form method="POST" action="">
                    <input type="hidden" name="submit-gutenberg" value="gutenberg">
                    <input type="image" src="<?php echo plugins_url('assets/img/Elementor.png', __FILE__); ?>" width=100% height=100%/>
                </form>
            </div>
                <?php } ?>
                <section class="generated-pages">
                <h2>Pages générées</h2>
                <div id="generated-pages">
                </section>
        </div>

<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    // Load the list of posts from local storage , parse = converts string into Javascript object
            // Load the list of posts from local storage
        const posts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('posts')) || [];

        // Check each post
        posts.forEach((post, index) => {
            // AJAX call to check if the post exists
            fetch('<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    action: 'check_post',
                    id: post.id
                }),
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                if (data.exists === false) {
                    // If the post doesn't exist, remove it from the DOM
                    const pageElement = document.getElementById(post.id);
                    if (pageElement) {
                        pageElement.parentNode.removeChild(pageElement);
                    }

                    // Remove the post from the list
                    posts.splice(index, 1);

                    // Store the updated list of posts in local storage
                    localStorage.setItem('posts', JSON.stringify(posts));
                }
            });
        });

    document.querySelectorAll('form').forEach(form => {
        form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            // Create a FormData object from the form
            const formData = new FormData(form);

            // Add the action name to the FormData object
            formData.append('action', 'create_post');

            // AJAX call
            fetch('<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData
            })
            // Waits for the response as JSON and converts the response to an object
            .then(response => response.json())
            //when Json conversion completed,
            .then(data => {
            // Append new page to the list
            const pageElement = document.createElement('p');
            pageElement.id = data.id; // Set the id attribute to the post ID

            const titleElement = document.createElement('span');
            titleElement.id = 'title-' + data.id;
            titleElement.textContent = `Title: ${data.title}`;

            const dateElement = document.createElement('span');
            dateElement.id = 'date-' + data.id;
            dateElement.textContent = `, Date: ${data.date}`;

            pageElement.appendChild(titleElement);
            pageElement.appendChild(dateElement);

            document.getElementById('generated-pages').appendChild(pageElement);

            // Add the new post to the list of posts
            posts.push(data);
            });
        });
    });
});
</script>
<script>
        function deletePost(postId) {
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "admin-ajax.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    action: "delete_post",
                    id: postId
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    if (response === "success") {
                        // Remove the pageElement
                        jQuery("#"+postId).remove();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
    <script>
    function deletePostDetails(postId) {
        // Remove the title
        jQuery("#title-"+postId).remove();

        // Remove the date
        jQuery("#date-"+postId).remove();
    }
</script>
<?php

    }
    /**
     * Create a new post with the content from the JSON file.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function create_post()
    {
        // Check if this is an AJAX request
        if (defined('DOING_AJAX') && DOING_AJAX && isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] === 'create_post') {
        if (isset($_POST['submit-gutenberg']) && $_POST['submit-gutenberg'] === 'gutenberg') {
            // Read the JSON file
            $json_data = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/partner.json');

            // Check if the JSON file was read successfully
            if ($json_data === false) {
                echo "Erreur de lecture du fichier JSON.";
                return;
            }

            // Decode the JSON data
            $block_data = json_decode($json_data, true);

            // Check if the JSON data was decoded successfully
            if ($block_data === null) {
                echo "Erreur lors du décodage du fichier JSON.";
                return;
            }

            // Retrieve the title, content, and sync status from the JSON data
            $title = isset($block_data['title']) ? $block_data['title'] : '';
            $content = isset($block_data['content']) ? $block_data['content'] : '';
            $sync_status = isset($block_data['syncStatus']) ? $block_data['syncStatus'] : 'draft';
            $img_url = isset($block_data['img_url']) ? $block_data['img_url'] : array();

            // Create a new post page
            $post_data = array(
                'post_title' => $title,
                'post_content' => $content,
                'post_status' => $sync_status,
                'post_type' => 'page', // You can change this as per your requirement
            );

            // Insert the post into the database
            $post_id = wp_insert_post($post_data);

            // Get the post title and date
            $post_title = get_the_title($post_id);
            $post_date = get_the_date('Y-m-d', $post_id);

             // Instead of returning plain text or HTML, return JSON data
             echo json_encode([
                'title' => $post_title,
                'date' => $post_date
            ]);
            wp_die(); // This is required to terminate immediately and return a proper response
        }

        }
    }
    function delete_post_title_and_date($post_id) {
        // Get the post
        $post = get_post($post_id);

        // If the post exists
        if($post) {
            // Delete the post title and date
            $post->post_title = '';
            $post->post_date = '';

            // Update the post
            wp_update_post($post);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Download an image from a URL and attach it to a post.
     *
     * @param string $image_url The URL of the image to download.
     * @param int $post_id The ID of the post to attach the image to.
     * @return int|WP_Error The attachment ID if successful, or a WP_Error object on failure.
     */

    public function download_image($image_url, $post_id)
    {
        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php');
        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');

        // Check if the image has already been attached to the post
        // TODO: Study the behavior of the error_log() function. It might be interesting to have an error tracking file to be able to fix them.
        $attachment_id = $this->get_attachment_id_by_url($image_url);
        if ($attachment_id) {
            // error_log("Found existing attachment ID: $attachment_id");
        } else {
            // Download the image and get the attachment ID
            // TODO: Add the AVIF format to the list of supported image formats with the flter apply_filters( ‘image_sideload_extensions’, string[] $allowed_extensions, string $file )
            $attachment_id = media_sideload_image($image_url, $post_id, null, 'id');
            if (is_wp_error($attachment_id)) {
                // error_log("Error downloading image: " . $attachment_id->get_error_message());
            } else {
                // error_log("Downloaded image and got attachment ID: $attachment_id");
            }
        }

        return $attachment_id;
    }
    public function ajax_delete_post() {
        // Check if the post ID is set
        if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
            // Delete the post
            $result = $this->delete_post($_POST['id']);

            // Send a JSON response
            wp_send_json($result);
        }
    }
    /**
     * Get the attachment ID of an image by its URL.
     *
     * @param string $url The URL of the image.
     * @return int|false The attachment ID if found, or false if not found.
     */
    public function get_attachment_id_by_url($url)
    {
        // Query to retrieve the attachment ID by the image URL
        // FIXME: Use another method to retrieve the attachment ID by the image URL if it possible.
        global $wpdb;
        $attachment = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE guid = %s", $url));
        return $attachment ? (int) $attachment : false;
    }
    public function delete_post($post_id) {
        // Globalize the WordPress database object
        global $wpdb;

        // Prepare a SQL statement to delete the post
        $stmt = $wpdb->prepare("DELETE FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE ID = %d", $post_id);

        // Execute the SQL statement
        $success = $wpdb->query($stmt);

        // Return a response
        if ($success) {
            return 'success';
        } else {
            return 'error';
        }
    }
}

new WoosterPartnerPresentation();


Can you please start with a proper explanation of what you actually want to achieve here?
